# When might someone say おしたいしておりました?

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

In what situation might a Japanese person say:

> 「おしたいして おりました。」

and what is it most commonly used to imply?

Answer (score 5):

> 「お[慕]{した}いしておりました。」

Basically, it is used in ***two*** different situations:

Romantic: To elegantly tell someone that you used to love him/her deeply.

Non-Romantic: To express how deeply you used to respect someone.